# Pythonでimport caffeが通らない

Tags: python

DeepDream等をいじりたく、Caffeの導入を進めております。
Pythonを主に使っているため、PyCaffeを利用したいのですが、

```
import pycaffe
```

とすると

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

と出てしまい、スタックしております。
解決策ご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

導入には、[本投稿](http://qiita.com/t-hiroyoshi/items/3bba01dd11b1241f1336)を参考に進め、import caffeまでは特段の問題はございませんでした。

Comment: Pythonのバージョンはなんでしょうか。

Comment: pythonは2.7.10です！

Comment: [英語だらけのページ](http://installing-caffe-the-right-way.wikidot.com/start)ですが、[このスレ](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/591#issuecomment-107082074)から[Caffeとpycaffeのインストールのアプローチ](http://installing-caffe-the-right-way.wikidot.com/start)はどうですか。この問題はPythonのバージョンに関係があるみたいですが。デフォルトのPythonはBrewのPythonを妨げる傾向があるのだと思います。

Comment: [この記事](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shu223/20160103/1452000295)とか参考になるかもしれません

Comment: [公式ドキュメント](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html)によればUbuntuで実績があるようですから、VirtualBoxでも入れてそちらで試した方が良いのでは？あえてMacで荊の道を行く必要はないでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Dockerで環境構築してあるものを使うことにいたしました。